# fetch data from two excel sheet with the data provider annotation in selenium hybrid framework

Tags: java, excel, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Hi I am using data provider to fetch the  data from the excel in selenium webdriver with the hybrid framework, I am want to create a master test suite file to maintain the run mode of the test case, Please help me out in the same.

```
         @DataProvider(name="hybridData")
public Object[][] getDatafromDataprovider() throws IOException
{
    Object[][] object=null;
    POIexcel file=new POIexcel();


        XSSFSheet sheet=file.readexcel("Filepath", "File name ", "Sheet name ");
        int rowcount=sheet.getLastRowNum()-sheet.getFirstRowNum();
        System.out.println("row count is" +rowcount);
        int col_count=sheet.getRow(1).getPhysicalNumberOfCells();
        object=new Object[rowcount][col_count];
        for(int i=0;i<rowcount;i++)
        {
            XSSFRow row=sheet.getRow(i+1);
            for (int j = 0; j < row.getLastCellNum(); j++) {
                //Print excel data in console
                XSSFCell cell=row.getCell(j);
                object[i][j] = cell.toString(); 
                System.out.println("values are"+" " +object[i][j]);
            }
        }



        return object;
```

[image]

Comment: sorry i didnt get you. What you meant by master test suite file?

Comment: @santhoshkumar these steps are  for a single test case , now I have created multiple test cases in the same sheet with multiple steps , now I want to manage these test cases in the different sheet so that I can set the run mode to execute or not to execute.

Comment: so you mean each sheet for each test case and master test sheet to control the execution

Comment: Yes , or I can put all the test cases in single sheet and a master sheet to control the execution.

Comment: Dude.., do something like this. Prepare one master sheet, which has test case number in one column, test case description in one column, respective  test sheet (sheet name) in one column,(here i am considering master plus test sheets in same workbook) and execution status (yes or no in another column). write code like, For each row in this master sheet (basically each test case) check the execution column and if its '"yes" then go the particular sheet(sheet name can be fetched from a column in the same row) and execute it.